# Using nvdisasm to generate control flow image of PTX code

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu, ptx, intermediate-language

I have a single file of CUDA code compiled to intermediate language PTX code, *example.ptx*. I would be interested to start poking around with this short file, trying to understand how it works.

I don't have previous experience fiddling around with intermediate code representation, but what I gather is that I can some how print out a figure of the control flow, to support me trying to reverse engineer this. [Cuda Binary Utilities](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#axzz3lONRPxm5) mention nvdisasm and shows nice Graphviz figures of the control flow, but it seems to work only for cubin files. I understand that these cubin files are optimized further from PTX, depending on the current GPU architecture.

My question is: Can I use nvdisasm to generate control flow image from *example.ptx*, or compile the ptx file to a cubin file, and use that to generate the image?

Comment: No, because PTX is a virtual machine language, not actual executable machine cone

Answer (score 2):

> or compile the ptx file to a cubin file, and use that

Yes, you can do that.  Compile your ptx file to a cubin with:

```
nvcc example.ptx -cubin
```

(the result will be in `example.cubin` or you could add e.g. `-o myfile.cubin` to name it something else)

This cubin file can be fed to [nvdisasm](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#nvdisasm) for processing.